# How to hide android navigation bar (android os 4.x)?

Tags: android

I add a KeyButtonView in navigation_bar.xml to do hiding navigation bar.
Then I find this view in PhoneStatusBar.java and set an onClickListener in the following:

> ```
> View.OnClickListener = new onClickListener()
> {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v)
>     {
>         v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
>     }
> };
> ```

But it doesn't work.

If I set mNavigationBar visibility View.GONE/INVISIBLE, the navigation bar becomes invisible, it still occupies the original area.

If I use WindowManager.removeView to remove mNavigationBar, it is gone. But I can't click the bottom area of screen to show Navigation bar again.

Do some people know how to do the right way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar with this code (You can remove the options which are not useful for you):

```
   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
           View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: I can't call getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(...) because my code is not in an Activity.
My code is writing in the PhoneStatusBar.java of SystemUI in the framewrok.
Even I setSystemUiVisibility using these flags, it still doesn't work.